# Fetching a specific element from an XML document with Python

Tags: python, xml

I need to fetch the following list:

https://support.content.office.net/en-us/static/O365IPAddresses.xml

There is a product called Identity, and I need to fetch the IPv4 addresslist underneath it. Is it possible to 'select' that element and stick it in a Python array? If this was JSON it'd be done by now, I tried to convert the doc to JSON but my usual module for doing that doesn't like it.

All the tutorials I've seen mention looping over the root, but in JSON I'd just select the data I wanted, surely there's a way to do that with XML? I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` has a (limited) XPath expression support that should be enough for your needs. Assuming you have loaded the xml data in an `Element` named tree ( `tree = xml.ElementTree.tree.parse(fd)` ), you can use `findall` to extract all relevant tags, and `findtext` to  extract the text from a tag. So this should be enough:

```
addrlist = [ ad.findtext(".") for ad in tree.findall(
                  "./product[@name='Identity']/addresslist[@type='IPv4']/address") ]
```